# Django - download image from url using external script and insert them into imageField

Tags: python, django, django-models, request

I am working on website **(Django 2.1)** with embeded videos, I need to fill my DB using external script. I have two tables one is parent (Video) and child table (Thumbnail) where is imageField. I need to download thumbnails from url and programmatically insert image into ImageField. I am fighting with this problem 2 days. I have read several advices here on stackoverflow but nothing work for me, I am giving up here. Can somebody help me please?

**Here is part of my models:**

```
#my models.py

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    video_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, unique = True)

class Thumbnail(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumb/', null=True, blank=True)
    thumb_resolution = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    videos = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='thumbnails')
```

**Here is simplified version of my downloading code, I tried several different ways but most of attempts ends without error but no files are in MEDIA folder. But my OneToMany relation between Video and Thumbnail is created successfully.**

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "video.settings")
import django
django.setup()
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from mainSite.models import Video, Thumbnail

def download(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url) 
        if not r.status_code == 200:
            raise Exception('file request failed with status code: ' + str(r.status_code))
        return (r.content)
    except Exception as ex:
        print (ex)
        return ('error')

VIDEO_URL = "https://videowebsite.com/video/43332"
VIDEO_THUMBS = ["https://videowebsite.com/thumb/1.jpg","https://videowebsite.com/thumb/2.jpg"]

# title, slug , video_url exist in my code
add_video = Video(title=title,slug=slug,video_url=video_url)
add_video.save()

for image in VIDEO_THUMBS:
    get_file = download(image)
    file_name = image.split('/')[-1]
    if get_file != 'error' and len(get_file) > 0:
    # I tried several different ways here but none of them work.


        f = BytesIO(get_file)
        Thumbnail(name=file_name, thumb=File(f), videos = add_video).save()
        #No error but image does not exist on server in MEDIA folder
        #--------------------------------------------
        with Image.open(get_file) as img:
            Thumbnail(name=file_name, thumb=ContentFile(img), videos = add_video).save()
            # ValueError: embedded null byte
        #--------------------------------------------
        Thumbnail(name=file_name, thumb=File(get_file), videos = add_video).save()
        # No error but image does not exist on server
        #--------------------------------------------
        with Image.open(get_file) as img:
            Thumbnail(name=file_name, thumb=File(img), videos = add_video).save()
        # No error but image does not exist on server
        #--------------------------------------------
        f = BytesIO(get_file)
        with Image.open(f) as img:
            Thumbnail(name=file_name, thumb=File(img), videos = add_video).save()
        #Again no error but images does not exist
    else:
        print('error')
```

I am really lost here, can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here? In most cases there is no error, relationship between Parent table and child table is created successfully, but images are not uploaded in MEDIA/thumb folder. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**:

```
from io import BytesIO

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from PIL import Image


for image in VIDEO_THUMBS:
    get_file = download(image)
    file_name = image.split('/')[-1]

    # please read https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html
    # for available formats.
    extension = 'jpeg'

    f = BytesIO(get_file)
    out = BytesIO()

    image = Image.open(f)
    image.save(out, extension)

    t = Thumbnail(<all fields except thumb>)
    t.thumb.save(file_name, ContentFile(out.getvalue()), save=False)
    t.save()
```

- Save file to memory [variable `out`]
- Use Django's `ContentFile` class to initialize with in-memory file contents

**EDIT**: You don't need `StringIO`, `BytesIO` will do the job.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried your solution and it complain that "No module named 'StringIO'". I changed import to "from io import StringIO". I am using python 3.6. Then I successfully executed script, but new error on line "image.save(out, extension)" ---> TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

Answer (score 0):

So far I was able to overcome it, but I had to save image to disk, then read file again, that works as I need.

```
for image in VIDEO_THUMBS:
    get_file = download(image)
    file_name = image.split('/')[-1]

    if get_file != 'error' and len(get_file) > 0:  
        with open('temp/temp.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(get_file)                
        with open('temp/temp.jpg', 'rb') as f:
            fi = f.read()
        t = Thumbnail(name=file_name, videos = add_video)
        t.thumb.save(file_name, ContentFile(fi), save=False)
        t.save()
    else:
        print('error')
```